# Choose dll to load at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-assembly

I have a source code base that is shared by two customers. My code has a dependency on a third party library.

One of my customers needs me to move to the newer version of the third party library and the other customer needs me to stay on the old version. The api of the library has NOT changed between versions.

The classes in third party library do NOT implement interfaces.

How can I keep my single source code base and dynamically load the right dll for each customer?

Comment: Have you looked at the option of using the `app.config` which can redirect an assembly to a specific version? You could then edit the `app.config` on a per-customer basis (assuming different computers/users)

Comment: Is the third party library managed or unmanaged code?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto we have looked at it, but I'd rather some sort of DI or MEF style solution.

Comment: @Polyfun it is managed code.

Comment: @HansPassant true, very good point. But I'm still interested in finding out how it could be done at runtime.

Comment: Question sounds like: how to do wrong thing in a right way. :) How often do you use this library in the code? You can load assemble using Assembly.Load method, find type by name, instantiate it. call member by name and so on. If you use this library often it would be a nightmare.